# Where can I find Stack Overflow Jobs?

Tags: support, android-app, jobs

I am new to the Stack Exchange application for Android. It seems more convenient than having to go to Google and search for the site that I want to go to.

However, I can't seem to find Stack Overflow Jobs in the app. If I see an ad for the site, it opens Chrome.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Comment: I meant in the app, sorry.

Comment: OK, next time please tag your question correctly so people don't get confused. You might also want to make it clear whether it's the iOS app or the Android app.

Comment: OK! I'll remember. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO Jobs is not implemented in the Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow applications. As of now you have to open a browser and navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs

You may post a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) about that but don't have much hope - the team doesn't have an iOS or Android developer anymore.